# discord.py | RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback

Tags: python, discord.py, python-asyncio

Commands in cog file dont work

main.py

```py
import discord, os
from discord.ext import commands
from games import Games

pr = '*'
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=pr, intents=discord.Intents.all())

bot.add_cog(Games)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():

    await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Game('Bot'))

    print('{0.user}'.format(bot))

bot.run('MTA5MDIzMjAwODAyNzk0NzAyOQ.GmB6JY.lupuAip5bsJRAK7AG52VE1GKMlK90mn-rs9D10')
```

games.py

```py
import discord
import random
from discord.ext import commands


class Games(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.command()
    async def slot(self, ctx, bet):
        row = ['', '', '', '', '', '']

        bet = int(bet)

        slot1 = random.choice(row)
        slot2 = random.choice(row)
        slot3 = random.choice(row)

        if slot1 is slot2 and slot2 is slot3:
            if slot1 == '':
                bet *= 1
            elif slot1 == '':
                bet *= 2
            elif slot1 == '':
                bet *= 3
            elif slot1 == '':
                bet *= 5
            elif slot1 == '':
                bet *= 4
            word = 'w'

        else:
            word = 'l'

        embed = discord.Embed(title=word, color=ctx.author.color)
        embed.add_field(name=f'{slot1} {slot2} {slot3}',
                        value='10')

        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
c:\bot\main.py:11: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'BotBase.add_cog' was never awaited
bot.add_cog(Games)

I dont have any ideas to fix it

Comment: ```'BotBase.add_cog' was never awaited``` means that 'add_cog' is a coroutine and needs to be awaited with ```await bot.add_cog(Games)```. This is new with Discord.py 2.0, which is the current Discord.py version. 
See [the documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=cog#discord.ext.commands.Bot.add_cog) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

### The error

```
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback c:\bot\main.py:11:
```

This means that you didn't [await](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#awaitables) an asynchronous function. This is a common error for this asynchronous library.

### Fixed code

```
@bot.event
async def on_connect():
    bot.add_cog(Games())  # The cog is instanced too
```

In the following code, I moved the `add_cog` function to `on_connect`. This is so the cogs will only be loaded when the bot connects to discord. Also note that the cog has to be instanced.

See this example [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/cogs.html)

Comment: That dont fix an error